# Only allow django admin on site id 1

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, django-sites

I want to only show the admin for my site with id 1.
In other views I've defined this in the `dispatch`, but I haven't found a way to do this for the admin.

I tried making a [custom admin class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class), but I didn't see a way to do this either.

Is there a way to define `dispatch` for admin, or limiting the sites where an admin shows?

The dispatch I'm using:

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if get_current_site(self.request).pk != settings.MY_SITE_ID:
            response = render(self.request, 'my_app/404.html')
            response.status_code = 404
            return response
    except Site.DoesNotExist:
        response = render(self.request, 'my_app/404.html', {'site_doesnotexist': True})
        response.status_code = 404
        return response

    return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different `ROOT_URLCONF` in the Settings file for the site with admin enabled. This `ROOT_URLCONF` would include the admin url patterns.

```
MY_SITE_ID = 1
ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.urls_with_admin'
```

```
# my_project/my_project/urls_with_admin.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns.append(url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls))
```

The base `urls.py` file, used by the other sites, would omit the admin patterns, making the admin inaccessible.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, all my sites use the same settings file. All sites have the same views and models too. How would I have a separate settings file for one site?

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were using the [Sites Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/), which is an optional part of Django and does have a separate settings file for each site. You can also use middleware to set `request.urlconf` for each request, but I'm not sure if `get_current_site` is callable from middleware.